# Why are one field of all objects in a list set to zero after using GROUP BY?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

In the following code,every object in val.supporters has name, supportamount and GFP, so everything is fine until there. When the positivesupporters list of supporter objects(positivesupporters list is on field of the class Player) is constructed, the GFP field is 0 for all supporters in the list. Why and what should I do to resolve this?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < result["modelData"]["rows"].Count; i++)
   {
    row = result["modelData"]["rows"][i];

    if (row["f"][0]["v"] != null && row["f"][1]["v"] != null)
  {
  if (dictionary.ContainsKey((string)row["f"][0]["v"]))
  val.supporters.Add(new Supporter { name = (string)row["f"][0]["v"], supportAmount = (double)row["f"][1]["v"], GFP = dictionary[(string)row["f"][0]["v"]] });
   }
   }


  val.positiveSupporters = val.supporters.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Supporter { name = x.Key, supportAmount = x.Sum(y => y.supportAmount)}).ToList();
```

Comment: I would assume that you will need to select the GFP in your lambda statement as well. Since it is not selected, all the values are default to the default value of int which is 0.

Comment: blank part on the left is for taking notes?

Comment: without seeing your definition of what "dictionary" is and what is contained at that location I can not tell you how to fix it. What type of object is GFP?

Comment: GFP is double. and this is how the dictionary looks like:
            Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            dictionary.Add("USA", 1);

Comment: SurgeonofDeath I know but how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or better yet, get the GFP in the second part of the process. It seems it's a lookup based on the grouping key.

```
var positiveSupporters = supporters.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Supporter { name = x.Key, supportAmount = x.Sum(y => y.supportAmount), GFP = dictionary[x.Key] }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I hadn't selected the GFP and it was set to default which is 0. Given that each name has a fixed GFP in my problem, I used firsr() to select the GFP:

```
val.positiveSupporters = val.supporters.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Supporter { name = x.Key, supportAmount = x.Sum(y => y.supportAmount),GFP = x.First().GFP}).ToList();
```